# How to show multiple images using only one image tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently having problem displaying multiple images using only one `img` tag and whose `src` is changed continuously. Here is my code:

```
<script>
  var i=0;

  function swapImage() {
    document.slide.src = 'image'+i+'.jpg';

    i++; 
    setTimeout('swapImage()',3000);
  }

</script>
<img class='materialboxed' width='350px' height='250px' src='CCTV.jpg' name='slide'>
```

But my code only displays one image then shows it in a kind of slideshow but rather i want to display all of them at once in a kind of for and while loop if possible.

Comment: Where do you define `i`?

Comment: @Tresdin see the changes!

Answer (score 2):

The thing is, you have not executed `swapImage` yet.

```
var i = 0;
(function swapImage() {
  document.slide.src = 'image' + i + '.jpg';

  i++;
  setTimeout('swapImage()', 3000);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use id instead of name (`<img src="" ... id="slide" />`) for the image and then use `document.getElementById('slide').src = ...`.

Comment: While using `id` instead of `name` is definitely more common and standard approach, that's not really the issue at hand.